TypeError when exporting point cloud layer to drive with QgsPointCloudLayerExporter.doExport() via PyQGIS
I am trying to save some point cloud layers to disk without benefiting from the GUI export (that is to say using PyQGIS commands).
The point cloud layers are results of earlier filtering that I applied on a .las file.
So-far I found QgsPointCloudLayerExporter which theoretically should allow me to define layer attributes such as CRS and ultimately save the layer on disk.
I can not see how I can benefit from this class or any other available tool in PyQGIS to do so.
As a start point I wrote:
layers_names = []
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    layers_names.append(layer.name())
    print(layer.name())

    exporter = QgsPointCloudLayerExporter
    exporter.fileName = layer
    exporter.crs = 'epsg:32631'
    print(exporter.fileName)
    exporter.doExport('new_las.las')

Which results in an error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 27, in <module>
TypeError: QgsPointCloudLayerExporter.doExport(): first argument of unbound method must 
have type 'QgsPointCloudLayerExporter'


You have to pass the layer you want to export to the constructor of QgsPointCloudLayerExporter. The crs, fileName and exportFormat parameters have to be set using the respective setter function. This code snippet worked for me. I use QGIS 3.34.9.
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsPointCloudLayerExporter, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

exporter = QgsPointCloudLayerExporter(iface.activeLayer())
exporter.setFileName('C:/Geodaten/output.las')
exporter.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32631'))
exporter.setFormat(QgsPointCloudLayerExporter.ExportFormat.Las)
exporter.doExport()


In case you want to export all MapLayers, you can iteratively export your mapLayers in a for loop:
from qgis.core import QgsPointCloudLayerExporter, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem
from qgis.core import Qgis

for i, layer in enumerate(QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()):
    if layer.type() != Qgis.LayerType.PointCloud:
        continue
    exporter = QgsPointCloudLayerExporter(layer)
    exporter.setFileName(f'C:/Geodaten/output_{i}.las')
    exporter.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32631'))
    exporter.setFormat(QgsPointCloudLayerExporter.ExportFormat.Las)
    exporter.doExport()


Thanks a lot for this correction and explanation. In case I have more than one layers in my layers lists, I would like to iteratively access them and export them. This is why I tried using the for loop and saving layer names inside a list. Will it be possible to iteratively change the status of "active layer" and assign it to a new element of the list?

i edited my answer accordingly

Perhaps it is better to use output_{layer.name()}, instead of output_{i} for matching purposes. Everything else was done perfectly!
